# Python Listbox shown before but not populated after request

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, listbox, tkinter

i have a tkinter listbox that should list the contents of mysql information_schema so i can select which database i want to connect too the list is converted to a tuple and shown in a list box, the listbox appears empty because i have not connected, but remains unpopulated after i connect, also the scroll bars are not connected to the listbox, but appear in the lower right of the window:

```
def mysqlConnect():
    import pymysql
    sqlUsr = MysqlUsr.get()
    sqlpwd = Mysqlpwd.get()
    conn = pymysql.connect(host='192.168.0.27', user= sqlUsr, passwd=sqlpwd, db='information_schema')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM SCHEMATA")
    schema_names = cursor.fetchall()
    schema_tuple = tuple(schema_names)
    countrynames = (schema_tuple)
    cnames = (countrynames)
    conn.close()

    # Figure out which country is selected, which gift is selected with the
    # radiobuttons, "send the gift", and provide feedback that it was sent.
    def sendGift(*args):
       idxs = lbox.curselection()
       if len(idxs)==1:
          idx = int(idxs[0])
    lbox.see(idx)
    name = countrynames[idx]
    # Gift sending left as an exercise to the reader
    sentmsg.set("%s %s" % (commands[gift.get()], name))

    # Note we're using the StringVar() 'cnames', constructed from 'countrynames'

    usertxt=Label(mainframe, text="User =")
    userlabel=Label(mainframe,text=usr)
    pathlabel=Label(mainframe, text="Project directory path is P:\\Projects_2013\\")
    projectdetaillabel=Label(mainframe, text="Project detail:")
    enternewname=Label(mainframe, text="Enter NEW project name:")
    ttk.Entry(mainframe, textvariable= assetVar).grid(column=4, row=2,columnspan=2, sticky=(W,E))
    createbutton=Button(mainframe, width=18,text="Create Folders", command=genAsset)
    selectlabel=Label (mainframe, text='Select an existing project:')
    browsebutton=Button(mainframe, width= 18,text="Browse", command=sel_Browse)
    prjtnm = Entry(mainframe, width=50)
    optionlabel=Label (mainframe, text="Project options:")
    completedbutton=Button(mainframe, text="Mark as completed", command=fldrRename)
    openbutton=Button(mainframe, width=18,text="Open Directory", command=Open_Win_Explorer_and_Select_Dir)
    shortcutlabel=Label(mainframe, text="Program Shortcuts:")
    xenonbutton=Button(mainframe, image=xenonimage, command=opn_xenon)
    wdebutton=Button(mainframe, image=webdateimage, command=opn_data_extr)
    wcebutton=Button(mainframe, image=webcontimage, command=opn_content_extr)
    htbutton=Button(mainframe, image=htimage, command=opn_ht)
    mysqllabel=Label(mainframe, text="Mysql:")
    mysqlbutton=Button(mainframe, width=18,text="MySql connect:",command=mysqlConnect)
    mysqlusr=Label(mainframe, text="Mysql Username:")
    mysqlusrentry=Entry(mainframe, width=18,textvariable= MysqlUsr)
    mysqlpasswordlabel=Label(mainframe, text="Mysql Password:")
    mysqlpwdentry=Entry(mainframe, width=18,textvariable= Mysqlpwd)
    lbox = Listbox(mainframe, listvariable=cnames, height=6)
    g0 = ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Select Database")
    g1 = ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Option:")
    g2 = ttk.Radiobutton(mainframe, text=commands['dbconnect'], variable=gift, value='dbconnect')
    g3 = ttk.Radiobutton(mainframe, text=commands['dbdelete'], variable=gift, value='dbdelete')
    send = ttk.Button(mainframe, text='Apply', command=(sendGift), default='active')
    sentlbl = ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=sentmsg, anchor='center')
    status = ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=statusmsg, anchor=W)

    # create a vertical scrollbar to the right of the listbox
    yscroll = tk.Scrollbar(command=lbox.yview, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
    yscroll.grid(row=15, column=3, sticky='ns')
    lbox.configure(yscrollcommand=yscroll.set)


    #grid all the above
    usertxt.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=E)
    userlabel.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=W)
    pathlabel.grid(column=4, columnspan=2, row=1, sticky=W)
    projectdetaillabel.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=E)
    enternewname.grid(column=2, row=2, columnspan=2, sticky=E, pady=15)
    lbox.grid(column=3, row=15, rowspan=6, sticky=(N,S,E,W))
    prjtnm.grid(row=3,column=4, columnspan=2)
    createbutton.grid(column=6, row=2, sticky=E, padx=10)
    selectlabel.grid(column=2,row=3,columnspan=2, sticky=E, pady=10)
    browsebutton.grid(row=3,column=6, sticky=W, padx=10)
    optionlabel.grid(row=4, column=2, columnspan=2, sticky=E)
    completedbutton.grid(row=4,column=4, sticky=W, padx=2)
    openbutton.grid(row=4,column=5, sticky=E, padx=2)
    shortcutlabel.grid(column=1, row=6,sticky=E, pady=60)
    xenonbutton.grid(row=6, column=3,sticky=E,)
    wdebutton.grid(row=6, column=4)
    wcebutton.grid(row=6, column=5)
    htbutton.grid(row=6,column=6,sticky=W,)
    mysqllabel.grid(column=1, row=8,sticky=E)
    mysqlbutton.grid(row=8, column=6, sticky=E, padx=10)
    mysqlusr.grid(row=8, column=2, sticky=E)
    mysqlusrentry.grid(row=8, column=3, sticky=W)
    mysqlpasswordlabel.grid(row=8, column=4, sticky=E)
    mysqlpwdentry.grid(row=8, column=5, sticky=W)
    g0.grid(column=3, row=14, sticky=W)
    g1.grid(column=4, row=14, sticky=W)
    g2.grid(column=4, row=16, sticky=W, padx=20, pady=10);
    g3.grid(column=4, row=17, sticky=W, padx=20);
    send.grid(column=5, row=16, sticky=E)
    sentlbl.grid(column=3, row=17, columnspan=2, sticky=N, pady=5, padx=5);
    status.grid(column=4, row=18, columnspan=2, sticky=(W,E));
    lbox.bind('<Double-1>', sendGift)
    root.bind('<Return>', sendGift)

    # Colorize alternating lines of the listbox
    #for i in range(0,len(countrynames),2):
    # lbox.itemconfigure(i, background='#f0f0ff')

    # Set the starting state of the interface, including selecting the
    # default command to connect, and clearing the messages.  Select the first
    # country in the list; because the <<ListboxSelect>> event is only
    # generated when the user makes a change, we explicitly call showPopulation.
    gift.set('dbconnect')
    sentmsg.set('')
    statusmsg.set('')
    lbox.selection_set(0)


    #add mysql pre-programmes queries here:
    ttk.Button(mainframe, width=18, text="Mysql query 1").grid(row=120, column=2, sticky=E)

    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you report stems from this line:

```
lbox = Listbox(mainframe, listvariable=cnames, height=6).grid(column=3, row=13, rowspan=6, sticky=(N,S,E,W))
```

In python, if you do `foo=bar().baz()`, `foo` gets the result of the last function in the chain. Thus, when you do `lbox = Listbox(...).grid(...)`, `lbox` gets the result of the call to grid, which is always `None`. Thus, `lbox` is `None`, and thus you get the error `NoneType object has no attribute yview` when the scrollbar tries to sync up with the listbox.

You should always separate the creation of widgets from the layout. It avoids this problem, and in my opinion it makes your code easier to write, understand and maintain.

Comment: ok i have edited all my code and seperated the widgets from the layout for the whole program, but now the listbox shows on startup, but of course its empty as i have not entered my username and password to connect to the database Although i no longer get an error but also the scroll bar is no longer linked to the listbox, its now sat in the bottom right hand corner of the main window ? I'll edit the code above so you can see

Comment: the more i stare at this the more confused i get, i'm assuming that issue is because the listbox is populated by the mysqlconnect function, but that function is not called until the connect button is pressed therefor there is nothing to put in the listbox, but as the box is already there and empty it doesnt get refreshed and the data added to it after pressing the button ?? does this mean the list box should only be created AFTER the connection button has been pressed ?

Comment: @jon141: no, you can create the listbox ahead of time. You can use the `insert` method to insert data whenever you want. So, do a query, then insert into the listbox.

Comment: many thanks listbox.insert(0,cnames) has now put the contents of the tuple (cnames) into the listbox, but the contents are all on one long line as in one entry, rather than seperate lines for each item, but i feel i'm getting somewhere, cheers. :)